# How to prevent the GridView from sptting out the width attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

By default, it seems that the GridView spits out `<table style="width:100%"...>`, which I don't want.  I would like not to specify width at all, in which case the browser will figure out how wide the table needs to be.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you include some more information the GridView output?

Comment: @Kane.  There is really nothing to add.  If I do nothing, it adds style="width:100%" attribute to the table tag.

Answer (score 1):

All the ASP.NET controls modify their html output based on the browser that is viewing the page.  For instance, if I add a GridView without any properties to my page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

I get the following html generated for IE7:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="myGrid" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

Due to company policies, I don't have any other browsers installed, so I cannot test to see if a width value is generated for different browsers.  I only get a width value if I explicitly set a `Width` in the GridView declaration.